# csv-parse invalid record length for fields with quotes

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-csv-parse

I am trying to parse the below two records. I asked a question earlier that fixed the record I had been trying to parse, but now my client is saying the below two records don't work. I'm also getting a different error this time: Invalid Record Length: columns length is 19, got 17

Here are the records (top has one record and bottom is from a different file that has multiple records):

```
lineItemXref,sku,poStatus,transactionDate,requestedShipDate,estimatedReceiptDate,qtyOrdered,qtyOpen,qtyCanceled,qtyReceived,vendorCode,contractedPrice,openExtendedCost,locationCode,poNumber,fileUpdate,notes,vendorNotes,vendorSku
USR355-1,ISHD00WTUS-00478,Pending Receipt,09/21/2021,12/22/2021,02/10/2022,1944,1944,0,0,77,16.00,31104,DISTRIBUTION ALTERNATIVES,USR355-1,12/31/2021,"InStyler BLU Turbo Ionic Dryer 
-Project: ISHDD
-US Retail
-White
-TUV Certification
-120V
-9ft Cord; Plug Type A
-Retail Box-revised A/W to ""TURBO IONIC""
-Instruction Manual
-Hard Diffuser removed
-New Pulp Tray without diffuser cavity
-Concentrator (small version)
-Rating Label
-Cord Label
-Check Point label
-Sensormatic Security Label",,

    lineItemXref,sku,poStatus,transactionDate,requestedShipDate,estimatedReceiptDate,qtyOrdered,qtyOpen,qtyCanceled,qtyReceived,vendorCode,contractedPrice,openExtendedCost,locationCode,poNumber,fileUpdate,notes,vendorNotes,vendorSku
PO510-4,80150-BUF-OAKR-1,Pending Receipt,05/16/2021,1/15/2022,2/26/2022,110,110,0,0,726,75.00,8250,Destined for Consolidation,PO510,01/18/2022,"Copenhagen Sideboard Oak Rattan Box 1
""SAILORSB01-W Melamine Plastic Rattan""
",,SAILORSB01-W Melamine Plastic Rattan
PO510-5,80150-BUF-OAKR-2,Pending Receipt,05/16/2021,1/15/2022,2/26/2022,110,110,0,0,726,47.50,5225,Destined for Consolidation,PO510,01/18/2022,"Copenhagen Sideboard Oak Rattan Box 2
""SAILORSB01-W Melamine Plastic Rattan""
",,SAILORSB01-W Melamine Plastic Rattan
PO510-6,80200-BUF-OAK,Pending Receipt,05/16/2021,1/15/2022,2/26/2022,110,110,0,0,726,102.00,11220,Destined for Consolidation,PO510,01/18/2022,"Visby Sideboard Oak
""LINESB02 Melamine""",,LINESB02 Melamine
```

There are 19 header columns, and when you count the record columns (using comma as delimiter), there are 19. I'm not sure why it doesn't parse correctly. Here is the code I'm currently using which works for all quoted fields except the records above. There must be a param I'm missing or something. I'm using csv-parse with node js. Any help would be appreciated. My client is panicking!

```
public async processCSV (tenant: string, files: { [field: string]: MultipartFileContract | MultipartFileContract[] }) : Promise<any[]> {
    try {
      for (const file of Object.values(files)) {
        const f = file as MultipartFileContract

        // @ts-ignore
        const filePath = path.resolve(f['csv'].tmpPath!)
        const records: any[] = []

        const parser = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(parse({ columns: true, relax: true, escape: '\\' }))

        for await (const record of parser) {
          records.push(record)
        }

        return records
      }

      return []
    } catch (err) {
      throw ServiceHelper.handleError('DataImportService.processCSV', err)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you include any error messages in this post? I read 20 columns on first line too

Comment: Also save in Notepad++, then try and load in Excel.. See how data loads up. Try re-saving as new csv file. see if quotes change.

Comment: I say what the error message is in the opening paragraph. Data loads fine in Excel. Quotes don't change. I have no control over how the file is going to come from the client. There are 19 header columns and 19 comma delimited fields in each record. I need to know how to properly parse a csv file with the records in my message.

Comment: Perhaps highlight the message in bold, because even after a re-read it's unclear to me.

Comment: It's just sometimes strings even with spaces need quotes. If the worst comes to the worst, it's not too difficult to write your own csv parser.. Have a boolean you switch on every time you find a quote, and switch off every second. If a comma comes when the boolean is on, it's part of a string. The next thing to content with is nested double, triple at the end, or quadruple for a single quote on it's own.